# Spanning polytopes

Tags: graph-theory, polytopes

Hamiltonian cycles (seen as **spanning polygons**) are interesting for several reasons (only a few of which I am aware of), but especially because *not* every connected graph has a Hamiltonian cycle (is Hamiltonian), so the characterization of Hamiltonian graphs becomes interesting (see wikipedia article on [Hamiltonian paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy.E2.80.93Chv.C3.A1tal_theorem)).

Side note: Each platonic and archimedian solid is Hamiltonian.

What about **spanning polytopes**, as
one possible generalization of
Hamiltonian cycles = spanning polygons?

(By "spanning polytope" I mean a spanning subgraph that is the 1-skeleton of a polytope of arbitrary dimension.)

There are connected graphs without spanning polytopes (trees obviously), but there are non-Hamiltonian graphs that have a spanning polytope of dimension d>2, e.g. the [Herschel graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HerschelGraph.html).

A [google search for "spanning polytope"](http://www.google.de/search?q=%22spanning+polytope%22) yields only very few and unrelated results, so my question is:

> Is there research on this or a related
>   topic, only under another name?

If not so, does this have an obvious - or not so obvious - reason?

Comment: Amos Altshuler studied a somewhat related notion in his Ph. D. thesis and the paper "Altshuler, Amos Manifolds in stacked $4$-polytopes. J. Combinatorial Theory Ser. A 10 1971 198--239." For more details see this MO answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27894/generalization-of-hamiltonian-cycles-to-hamiltonian-spheres/29264#29264


Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no known good characterization of which graphs are the 1-skeleton of some polytope in some dimension d. There are several interesting properties of polytope graphs that may be of interest to you:

$\bullet$ In $\mathbb{R}^3$, Steinitz's theorem characterizes all polytopal graphs as the planar 3-connected graphs.

$\bullet$ In d > 3, the cyclic polytopes have $K_n$ as a 1-skeleton. A result of Perles implies that every graph $G$, $G$+$K_n$ is a d-polytopal graph for some n and some d, although it is unknown what the minimum n is for a given $G$.

$\bullet$ It is a theorem of Balinski that the graph of a polytope in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is d-connected, so graphs with polytopal spanning subgraphs must have a highly connected subgraph.

There are also results about how to determine whether a specific graph $G$ is a polytopal graph, but they do not extend into a classification of all polytopal graphs.

There have been studies into classes of abstract polytope graphs, classes which contain all the 1-skeletons of polytopes but likely contain graphs with no polytopal realization, for example in this paper of Eisenbrand, Haehnle, and Rothboss [Diameter of Polyhedra: Limits of Abstraction](http://sma.epfl.ch/~eisenbra/Publications/designs.pdf)

For more information, check out Gil Kalai's chapter 19 in the *Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry* by Jacob E. Goodman and Joseph O'Rourke (or Gil Kalai's excellent blog gilkalai.wordpress.com/ ) or Grunbaum's *Convex Polyopes*.